# Split a string into columns in BigQuery using delimeter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in Google BigQuery. I need help with the SQL syntax for a query which will work with the functions that are available in GoogleSQL for BigQuery.

In the first column of the table below are examples of my data. The three columns next to it are what I am trying to achieve.

| Data | Prefix | Suffix | Base |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male_Bob_1 |  | 1 | Male_Bob |
| Female_Jenny_2 |  | 2 | Female_Jenny |
| Female_Brittany |  |  | Female_Brittany |
| New_Male_Henry_8 | New | 8 | Male_Henry |
| Backup_Male_Henry_33 | Backup | 33 | Male_Henry |
| Backup_Female_Jane_304 | Backup | 304 | Female_Jane |
| Loaned_Male_John_9 | Loaned | 9 | Male_John |

In my data column, there is a string of text with an underscore to separate the different sections within the string.

I would like to split the string into 3 columns:

1. Prefix column: return the prefix of the string (anything that comes before the word 'Male' or 'Female'), sometimes there will be no prefix in which case I would like to return a blank/null value. The string will always contain either the word 'Male' or 'Female' in it.
2. Suffix column: return the suffix of the string (any number that is contained at the end of the string), sometimes there will be no suffix in which case I would like to return a blank/null value
3. Base column: return the base of the string with the prefix & suffix parts from the previous two columns removed

---

I have tried the `SPLIT` function but it does not seem sophisticated enough for what I am trying to do, because it breaks apart the entire string and I would only like the prefix and suffix sections broken out.

I'm also not sure how to approach this in a way that effectively handles the exceptions in my data. For example, sometimes there is no prefix at all before the word 'Male' or 'Female', so in those instances it would not work to simply take all characters that appear before the first underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can try is to use regular expressions.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'Male_Bob_1' Data UNION ALL
  -- ...
  SELECT 'Loaned_Male_John_9'
)
-- query starts here
SELECT Data, 
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(Data, r'(^.*?)_?(?:Male_|Female_)') Prefix,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(Data, r'(\d*$)') Suffix,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(Data, r'(Male_.*?|Female_.*?)_?\d*$') Base,
  FROM sample_table;

-- query result
+------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|          Data          | Prefix | Suffix |      Base       |
+------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| Male_Bob_1             |        |      1 | Male_Bob        |
| Female_Jenny_2         |        |      2 | Female_Jenny    |
| Female_Brittany        |        |        | Female_Brittany |
| New_Male_Henry_8       | New    |      8 | Male_Henry      |
| Backup_Male_Henry_33   | Backup |     33 | Male_Henry      |
| Backup_Female_Jane_304 | Backup |    304 | Female_Jane     |
| Loaned_Male_John_9     | Loaned |      9 | Male_John       |
+------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

##### ■ *Regular expressions* explanation

- `Prefix` - https://regex101.com/r/x5BZhI/1
- `Suffix` - https://regex101.com/r/NcUs3A/1
- `Base` - https://regex101.com/r/GRNlah/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this exmple (tested for SQL Server)

```
with t as(
select *
  ,max(case when word='Male' or word='Female' then rn else 0 end)
        over(partition by data) iMale
  ,max(rn)
        over(partition by data) maxrn
  ,case when rn=max(rn)over(partition by data)
            and word like '[0-9]%'
        then rn
   end iSuffix
from test 
cross apply(select value word,row_number()over(order by (select 1)) rn
             from string_split(data,'_')) s
)
select data
  ,string_agg(case when rn<iMale then word end,'_') prefix
  ,max(case when rn=iSuffix then word end) suffix
  ,string_agg(case when rn>=coalesce(iMale,1) 
                    and rn<coalesce(iSuffix,maxrn+1)
                then word end,'_') base
  ,max(iSuffix) iSuffix
  ,max(iMale) iMale
from t
group by data
```

Test result (draft)

| Data | prefix | suffix | base | iSuffix | iMale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male_Bob_1 | null | 1 | Male_Bob | 3 | 1 |
| Female_Jenny_2 | null | 2 | Female_Jenny | 3 | 1 |
| Female_Brittany | null | null | Female_Brittany | null | 1 |
| New_Male_Henry_8 | New | 8 | Male_Henry | 4 | 2 |
| Backup_Male_Henry_33 | Backup | 33 | Male_Henry | 4 | 2 |
| Backup_Female_Jane_304 | Backup | 304 | Female_Jane | 4 | 2 |
| Loaned_Male_John_9 | Loaned | 9 | Male_John | 4 | 2 |
| Loaned_NoMale_John_9 | null | 9 | Loaned_NoMale_John | 4 | 0 |
| Loaned_NoMale_John_nonSuffix | null | null | Loaned_NoMale_John_nonSuffix | null | 0 |